# How would one search for a string in a column and return its presence as a boolean in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to test for the presence of a string in a range(a column for this application), and return whether or not it is present as a boolean. How would I do this? I tried FIND and MATCH, but they didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("string",A:A)))>0)
```

And if you want your search to be case sensitive you can use this one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(FIND("string",A:A)))>0)
```